# Calculate heart valve flow rates over time. What formulas are involed?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, simulation, liquid

I'm trying to program a simulation of a human heart which I want to produce results close to the following:
[image: Ventricle pressure of time (Heart cycle)]
(Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_cycle#/media/File:Wiggers_Diagram_2.svg)

For simplification I'm using the following model:

- Fixed time steps of 25ms
- Four Heart chambers having each the following properties

  - Capacity with negligible pressure (Relaxed)
  - Pressure increase per volume above negligible pressure capacity
  - Used capacity
  - Out valve area
  - Flow speed

For this question lets assume I have two flexible, slightly expandable chambers C1 and C2 which will have no pressure until volume V1 and V2 is reached. Any additional volume will increase the chamber pressure P1 and P2 by PV1 and PV2 (pressure per volume). Both chambers are connected by a initially shut valve with area A and are at the same height. The valve only allows flow in the direction from C1 to C2.

Further assume both chambers are each at their non pressurized volumes V1 and V2 and chamber C1 begins to contract exerting pressure p1(t) over time. For simplicity the valve is completely open at t>=0 unless the flow would be backwards (i.e. C2 to C1).

Now I need to calculate the volume which has flown from C1 into C2 and the flow rate at time steps tn(=n*25ms).

At first I though this should be relatively simple to calculate but as I dive deeper I'm starting to wonder if it is even feasible for me to calculate.

I started with the Bernoulli equation p1 + d*v1^2/2 + d*g*h1 = p2 + d*v2^2/2 + d*g*h2 which in this case can be simplified to p1 + d*v1^2/2 = p2 + d*v2^2/2 (h1=h2).
Then I though I could express the pressure p1 and p2 as a function over time and then integrate over time to get the volume but that lead nowhere. And that equation also doesn't handle the acceleration of resting fluids.

What formulas would be involved to calculate that?
If it turns out that is too complex, I'll try a different numeric approach but I'd prefer a solution based on physics.

(My math skills currently tops out at around single dimensional IVPs)

Comment: Continuity ie mass in = mass out.

Comment: That could help later in the process but I'm stuck before I know how much mass goes in as the liquid is resting and only starts to move once the contraction increases the pressure in the chamber. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Does the blood flow become stationary between heartbeats?

Comment: Yes in my model at least. But I don't know the mass which has flown between those two times.

Comment: To elaborate: The exerted pressure in C1 is a function of t which is similar to a negative parabola. So after peak pressure was achieved the pressure only drops and the flow to chamber C2 stops after the pressure in C1 and C2 is equivalent and the speed has dropped to zero. (C2 pressure rises due to the flow)

Comment: And I should also mention that the valve doesn't allow backwards flow. I'll edit the question accordingly.